# how to save taken images to use as background images?

Tags: ios, core-data, uiimagepickercontroller

In my application, you can take photos or choose photos from the library in order to use them as a background image later. 
I would like to ask for a tutorial that explains how to save these photos using Core Data.

Sorry if this question is not appropriate, I know that StackOverflow is only for code questions. And sorry for my bad English, I am Spanish.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here this is a nice [tutorial](http://maybelost.com/2011/12/tutorial-storyboard-app-with-core-data/). It teaches you how to use core data over all but it also teaches with pictures. By the way you need to create a new attribute with the type binary data to save the photo. Basically you need to convert your image into NSData and then save it in your attribute. To get it out convert NSData to a UIImage.

Comment: @yeker3 You welcome! By the way I edited my post so it summaries the tutorial.

Comment: Great tutorial! But pay attention to the fact that this tutorial is dealing with small images: the images are resized before saving them to Core Data.
If the poster wants to save bigger images (large photos), it might be more efficient to save these images on the disk and only keep a reference (identifier or path) to them in the Core Data store.